# Custom date auto fill

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to auto fill the following date pattern:

```
1-Sep-2014
1-Sep-2014
1-Sep-2014
2-Sep-2014
2-Sep-2014
2-Sep-2014
3-Sep-2014
3-Sep-2014
3-Sep-2014
```

If I select all the above cells, and pull down using auto-fill option, it has to fill as

```
4-Sep-2014
4-Sep-2014
4-Sep-2014
5-Sep-2014
5-Sep-2014
5-Sep-2014
6-Sep-2014
6-Sep-2014
6-Sep-2014
```

.
.
.
and so on.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Below your series put these formulas<sup>1</sup> in the next three cells -

```
=OFFSET(I1,1,)+3
=OFFSET(I2,1,)+3
=OFFSET(I3,1,)+2
```

**This assumes the first date is in `I1` - adjust as needed**

Then highlight those three cells and drag them down.

<sup>1</sup>Or, if you don't *want to make it needlessly complicated*, just use:

```
=I1+3
=I2+3
=I3+3
```